# HDF5: freeing memory chunks allocated by FAPL_CORE driver

Tags: c++, memory-management, hdf5

I am creating in-memory HDF5 files ([docs](https://confluence.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/H5P_SET_FAPL_CORE)) like this:

```cpp
H5::FileAccPropList accPList=H5::FileAccPropList::DEFAULT;
herr_t h5err=H5Pset_fapl_core(accPList.getId(),/* 4M chunks*/1<<22,/*backing_store*/false);
if(h5err<0) /* report error */;
H5::H5File h5file("unique-name-changing-for-every-invocation"),H5F_ACC_TRUNC,H5::FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT,accPList);
```

and this file (after adding datasets & getting the HDF5 image as bytes & sending the over the wire) gets eventually closed simply via

```cpp
h5file.close()
```

This happens periodically during the program execution, as remote incoming data are being processed.

What I see (both under Linux and Windows) is that the program usage keeps jumping up little by little (in increments corresponding to ~70MB of each HDF5 file image), eventually running out of RAM and getting OOM-killed.

Any pointer on how to ask the core (memory) I/O driver to free the memory?

I looked at the HDF5 sources; the [H5FD__core_close(H5FD_t *_file)](https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5/blob/5539d06d95cbfdddaf60656da2f393a450d2b670/src/H5FDcore.c#L962) function clearly should be freeing memory...